# webpacker is not installed successfully on rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, webpacker

Terminal: bash on Ubuntu on windows 10
Rails: 4.2.8
npm: 5.5.1
node: v8.9.1
yarn: 1.3.2

After `rake webpacker:install`, the console shows as follows. Although it shows "successfully installed" at the very end, some errors appear in the log. Is it normal?

```
  create  config/webpacker.yml
Copying webpack core config and loaders
  create  config/webpack
  create  config/webpack/development.js
  create  config/webpack/environment.js
  create  config/webpack/production.js
  create  config/webpack/test.js
Copying .postcssrc.yml to app root directory
  create  .postcssrc.yml
Copying .babelrc to app root directory
  create  .babelrc
Creating javascript app source directory
   exist  app/javascript
   identical  app/javascript/packs/application.js
Installing binstubs
     run  bundle binstubs webpacker from "."
  append  .gitignore
Installing all JavaScript dependencies
     run  yarn add @rails/webpacker coffeescript@1.12.7 from "."
yarn add v1.3.2
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.1.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "@rails/webpacker > postcss-cssnext@3.0.2" has unmet peer dependency "caniuse-lite@^1.0.30000697".
error An unexpected error occurred: "EINVAL: invalid argument, lstat '/mnt/d/Github/cfegame/node_modules/babel-core/package-lock.json'".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/mnt/d/Github/cfegame/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
Installing dev server for live reloading
     run  yarn add --dev webpack-dev-server from "."
yarn add v1.3.2
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.1.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@1.12.1" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^1.0.0 || ^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0".
warning " > webpack-dev-server@2.9.4" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^2.2.0 || ^3.0.0".
error An unexpected error occurred: "EINVAL: invalid argument, lstat '/mnt/d/Github/cfegame/node_modules/camelcase-keys/node_modules/camelcase/license'".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/mnt/d/Github/cfegame/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
Webpacker successfully installed
```

When I "successfully installed" webpacker and I want to check if webpack-dev-server worked properly, the console shows as follows. Did it mean I don't install webpacker properly?

```
(home_dir)/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/webpacker-3.0.2/lib/webpacker/dev_server_runner.rb:47:in `exec': No such file or directory - (project_dir)/node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server (Errno::ENOENT)
        from (home_dir)/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/webpacker-3.0.2/lib/webpacker/dev_server_runner.rb:47:in `block in execute_cmd'
        from (home_dir)/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/webpacker-3.0.2/lib/webpacker/dev_server_runner.rb:46:in `chdir'
        from (home_dir)/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/webpacker-3.0.2/lib/webpacker/dev_server_runner.rb:46:in `execute_cmd'
        from (home_dir)/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/webpacker-3.0.2/lib/webpacker/dev_server_runner.rb:11:in `run'
        from (home_dir)/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/webpacker-3.0.2/lib/webpacker/runner.rb:6:in `run'
        from (home_dir)/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/webpacker-3.0.2/exe/webpack-dev-server:8:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/webpack-dev-server:17:in `load'
        from bin/webpack-dev-server:17:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basically `yarn` is managing your packages. He is trying to install the `webpack-dev-server-` with `yarn add --dev webpack-dev-server from "."` but it fails. This is the documentation about that [`yarn add` command](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/add/)

`npm` is the alternative for using `yarn` for installing packages so in your server terminal run

```
npm install webpack-dev-server
```

and it should install the dependencies

> When I "successfully installed" webpacker and I want to check if webpack-dev-server worked properly, the console shows as follows. Did it mean I don't install webpacker properly?

```
(home_dir)/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/webpacker-3.0.2/lib/webpacker/dev_server_runner.rb:47:in `exec': No such file or directory - (project_dir)/node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server (Errno::ENOENT)
```

You either did not install it or your are searching the wrong path, maybe the gem is installed in `.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3somethingelse`

Some discussion you may want to read

https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2448

https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4188